# .delay() a .css() action by multiplying an index number

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a script that does the following:

1. Waits until a point on the page is reached by scrolling (`.clients` with an offset of `500px`
2. Start fading in `img`'s contained inside the `.clients` div once this event is triggered
3. Fade in with a slight delay between each item (so they fade in in sequence)

Due to other parts of my code **the fade-in has to be with change of `opacity:1` and cannot be `.fadeIn()`**

I'm somewhere there but having a few issues. Here is my code:

```
var targetOffset = $(".clients").offset().top;
var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $w.scrollTop() > targetOffset-500 ) {
        $('.home .clients img').each(function(index){
            console.log(index);
            $(this).delay(500 * index).css('opacity','1');
        });
     }
});
```

#### First problem

The event does fire at the correct scroll-point in the page, but it *continues to fire*. I would like it to *only fire once* and then not register again. When `500` above `.clients` is reached, the event should fire, and never again.

#### Second problem

My `.each()` does not seem to work correctly. Everything fades in at once. My method for making a small `.delay()` between the fade-ins doesn't seem to be working. I tried multiplying the `index` by 500. So the first index is 0, so it fires immediately. The second index is `1` so it should fire after `500` milliseconds and so on. I'd like to work out why this method isn't working.

Any help appreciated. I'd appreciate trying to make the code above work rather than writing something entirely new, unless that's the only way. I'd appreciate explanation of what I was doing wrong so I can learn, instead of just pure-code answers.

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pg3zveps/3/)

Comment: Use `setTimeout`. `setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).delay(500 * index).css('opacity', '1');
}, 500 * index);`

Comment: Define your else part.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal with what? Can you explain how that would help?

Comment: can you place your code in jsfiddle or anywhere else?

Comment: @HarshSanghani added JSfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidney has attacked most of the problems except one.  The scroll event fires multiple times, so it checks the conditional multiple times and then actually sets the animation multiple times.  To keep this from happening, I typically like to add another boolean to check if the process has fired at all.  I've simplified the code to make the changes more legible.

```
var working = false;
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 1000 && !working){
        working = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            working = false;
        }, 500);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar) mentioned in the comments below your post, instead of using `.delay()` you could use a plain `setTimeout()`.

On the jQuery docs for [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) they mention that using `setTimeout` is actually better in some use-cases too - this is one of them.

> The **.delay()** method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   *setTimeout* function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Using `setTimeout` your code would look like this:

```
var targetOffset = $(".clients").offset().top;
var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($w.scrollTop() > targetOffset - 500) {
        $('.home .clients img').each(function(index) {
            setTimeout(function() {
               $(this).css('opacity','1'); 
            }, (500 * index));
        });
     }
});
```

Also, you can unbind an event using [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

so in your `if ($w.scrollTop() > targetOffset - 500) { ... }`
you could add a line that looks like this:

```
$(window).off('scroll');
```

Which would unbind the scroll handler from the window object.
You could also use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to reattach it again some time later. (with `on()` you can bind multiple events in one go, allowing you to write the same code for multiple handlers once.)

Answer (score 0):

Please change your jquery code with following it will trigger event one time only and may be as per your reuirements :-

```
var targetOffset = $(".clients").offset().top;
var $w = $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($w.scrollTop() == 1300) {
        console.log('here!');

        $('.clients img').each(function (index) {
            $(this).delay(5000 * index).css('opacity', '1');
        });
    }
});
```

Here i have take scroll hight to 1300 to show your opacity effect you can take it dynamically, if you want it 500 then please change the css as following also.

```
.scroll {
    height:700px;
}
```